# How to create .EAR file for spring boot multi module Project?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, multi-module

I have created spring boot multi module  web project with one parent project and two child projects. It is having following structure.

```
Parent Project (Packaging type : POM)
    -First Child Project (web Project and Packaging type : Jar)
    -Second Child Project(Packaging type : Jar)
```

Comment: Add third child for the ear

Comment: @Jens, Yes your answer helps me.

Answer (score 1):

To create ear file for maven spring boot multi-module project I have created separate package with packaging type ear and after that I added dependency of other modules to this ear module so that my project structure is like below.

```
Parent Project (Packaging type : POM)
     -First Child module(web Project and Packaging type : war)
     -Second Child module(Packaging type : war)
     -Third Child module(Packaging type : jar)
     -fourth child module(Packaging type : ear)
```

where in fourth child module I have added dependency of first three modules and deployed this ear file on Enterprise Application Server like JBoss etc.